# Deprecated as a property in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha Touch 2 to build an application.  When I load the application into a browser, I am getting the following error: `[DEPRECATE][Anonymous] stores is deprecated as a property directly on the Ext.app.Controller prototype. Please put it inside the config object.`  I cannot figure out why this error is occurring.  Any help?  Thanks!  The first part of my MainController code is as follows:

```
config: {

    models: [
        'Tasks'
    ],

    stores: [
        'TaskList'
    ],

    views: [
        'MainCarousel',
        'StartScreen',
        'WhatScreen',
        'WhenScreen',
        'Login'
    ],


    refs: [{
        ref: 'mainCarousel',
        selector: 'maincarousel'
    }, {
        ref: 'whenScreen',
        selector: 'whenscreen'
    }, {
        ref: 'whatScreen',
        selector: 'whatscreen'
    }, {
        ref: 'startScreen',
        selector: 'startscreen'
    }, {
        ref: 'login',
        selector: 'login'
    }],
},
```

Comment: Can you post a code where you define stores in your application controller?

Comment: @sha I added the code where I define my stores to my question.  Thanks!

Comment: And all this inside config object, or just inside controller definition?

Comment: @sha It is just inside the controller definition.  Must it go inside a config object?

Comment: Yeap. Not `must` yet, but it's preferable way.

Comment: @sha Thanks! That has solved some of the errors.  I am still getting an error regarding the refs.  When I put the refs inside the config (see code above) the app breaks. The error says `In Sencha Touch 2 the refs config accepts an object but you have passed it an array.`  When I change the refs to an object, there are errors.  What do you think?

Comment: I posted it as an answer

Comment: @sha Thank you! It is working fine now.  I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `stores[]` array inside `config` object inside your controller definition:

```
...
config: {
   stores: [..]
}
...
```

As for defining `refs` inside controller check out Sencha doc on how to define refs http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller I don't think you're using it correctly.